# Why is there a difference between evaluating a defun during emacs startup vs. later?

Tags: debugging, emacs, elisp

I have a function with the following structure (I can post the whole definition if it is important, but I think it would be mostly distracting so for now I skipped this):

```
(defun my-func (...)
  (save-excursion
    (cl-block lp
      (let (...)
        (loop for ... in ... do
         ...
         (return-from lp ...))))))
```

And I also have

```
;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-
```

It used to work fine, suddenly I started getting the following error from this function:

```
return-from: No catch for tag: --cl-block-lp--, ("\\(" . "\\)")
```

This error is obviously false, as the tag does exist. Moreover, when trying to step through the function, I discovered that if I eval the definition again (after emacs has loaded), I do not get this error.

My questions are:

1. Why do I get this error in the first place?
2. What could cause this code to fail when it evals once while emacs is loading, and succeed when evaluated again?

---

P.S.

I'm not sure why I wrote it with a cl-block/return-from rather than throw/catch - possibly because I am using the loop construct. I changed it to throw/catch and it works now.

Comment: Of course, thanks! - I edited the definition in the browser and autocorrect messed this up.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that you forgot to `(require 'cl)` or `(require 'cl-lib)` somewhere, so the macros aren't expanded the way they should.  Notice also that you use `cl-block` (a macro from `cl-lib`) as well as `loop` and `return-from` (two macros fro `cl`).  Better not mix `cl` and `cl-lib` like that.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like a plausible explanation, and thanks for the tips as well! What is the complement to return-from in the cl package, if not cl-block (let me guess - block?)?

Comment: Ok, just for anyone happening to read this, block is indeed the complement to return-from (though on my system it is an alias to cl-block).